# How to put green box below yellow box in flutter layout?

Tags: layout

I am trying to learn flutter and I am using the course from appbrewery.co and in that course I've got a layout challenge in which I have to make a layout according to this picture:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1k7oW5qVLJqzw_lEFsOFS_qKmkGjBX1pL

But I am not able to do it because I cannot move the green box below the yellow box. I am trying to do it, but not able to do it and they've not given any solution either. Can anyone look at my code and tell me what I am not able to get ?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 650,
                width: 90,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Container(
                height: 650,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks.

[image: My layuot]

Answer (score 0):

what you have done is in Row that's why yellow and green is aside if you want to put one box to another than it should be in Column.

This might help you.

```
Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: Let me know if you get it.

Answer (score 0):

you also require:

```
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
```

after Column so that it is positioned horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap 2 square in a col and align to center.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```